# Sending HTTPS request to Chrome sync service - getting error 404

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to send a POST request to the Chrome sync service which is located at https://clients4.google.com.
I'm using that short piece of code to send a request that I captured before with the help of BURP Suite and saved to a file. It's what Chrome sends when connecting to the sync service.
That code opens an SSLSocket, connects to the Chrome server and sends the contents of that file (see below):

```
private void sendRequest() {
    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("clients4.google.com", 443);
    socket.startHandshake();

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    sendMessage(out, new File("request.bin"));
    readResponse(in);

    out.close();
    in.close();
}

private void sendMessage(BufferedWriter out, File request) throws IOException {
    List<String> result = getContents(request);
    for (String line : result) {
        out.write(line + "\r\n");
    }
    out.write("\r\n");
    out.flush();
}

private void readResponse(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

private List getContents(File file) throws IOException {
    List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        contents.add(line);
    }
    input.close();
    return contents;
}
```

The request.bin file looks like this (it's a plaintext request without SSL):

```
POST /chrome-sync/command/?client=Google+Chrome&client_id={VALID_CLIENT_ID} HTTP/1.1
Host: clients4.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1730
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth={MY_VALID_AUTH_DATA}
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
User-Agent: Chrome WIN 23.0.1271.97 (171054)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

{binary data}
```

Now this request fails as the server returns *HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found*.
But why does this happen? 
It's the exact same request Chrome sends, isn't it? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here: The problem was with the encoding. The binary data in the request body got slightly modified and that caused the Google server to respond with errorcode 404 (which is pretty confusing). 
Now that I'm using proper encoding everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you input `chrome://sync/` in your chrome's addr bar, you will see the server url is:

```
https://clients4.google.com/chrome-sync/dev
```

some more information you can find in this link:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90811

And /command? needs authentication. I found some info may be helpful for you. Check the comments of this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108186

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was aware of `chrome://sync` and for me it's the URL without "dev" (I guess it's a non-developer version of Chrome), but it doesn't change anything. Those links gave some insight, but shouldn't the request be authorized correctly, as it contains the `Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=...` header? That header stays the same whenever Chrome contacts the sync server, but for my own request (that's just a copy of the original one) it still doesn't seem to work …